# gcc -MM on cygwin: sometimes unix style paths

Tags: c++, bash, gcc, makefile, cygwin

I have a (legacy) bash script that parses a list of directories for source files and echos them into a makefile to create actual makerules with `gcc -MM`. The script works just fine, the problem is that running `make` on the generated makefile results in inconsistent path format in the makerules - while most makerules have mixed style paths (which is ok), some have cygwin style paths (not ok). This didn't happen on a very old (~2002 release) of cygwin.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fn_source=SourceFileList
fn_depmake=depMakefile
fn_orgMake=Makefile
fn_depIncl=Depend.incl
fn_optIncl=OptimizationCflags.incl

#
# create a Makefile to determine the dependencies
echo -n create dep-makefile ...\ 
#
# generate include for Optimization-File
#
echo >  $fn_depIncl
echo include $fn_optIncl >>  $fn_depIncl
echo >>  $fn_depIncl
#
touch  $fn_optIncl
#
echo > $fn_depmake

# CFLAGS options from Makefile
grep "^CFLAGS[ =]" $fn_orgMake | grep $BUILD_SPEC >> $fn_depmake
grep "^CFLAGS_AS[ =]" $fn_orgMake | grep $BUILD_SPEC >> $fn_depmake
grep "^CFLAGS_GCC[ =]" $fn_orgMake | grep $BUILD_SPEC >> $fn_depmake

echo -n  generate depMakefile ...

echo >> $fn_depmake

# the default rule
echo all: >> $fn_depmake 

FileList=`cat $fn_source`
incPath=""
rawIncPath=""
for fn in $FileList; do
   incPath=$incPath" -I"${fn%/*}
   rawIncPath=$rawIncPath" "${fn%/*}
done

# filter out redundant paths
echo  $incPath | \
sed -n -e 's/ /\
/gp' | \
sort -u > _tmp 
incPath=`cat _tmp`

# filter out redundant paths
echo  $rawIncPath | \
sed -n -e 's/ /\
/gp' | \
sort -u > _tmp 
rawIncPath=`cat _tmp`

#
# create file with include paths
#
echo LibIncludes=$incPath > LibIncludes

#
# put all source files with the same path in one gcc command
# 
for path in $rawIncPath; do 
   sourceFiles=`grep $path/ $fn_source`
   echo "   "echo do $path >> $fn_depmake
   echo "   "gcc -MM  '$(CFLAGS_GCC)' -I$path $sourceFiles \>\> _tmp >> $fn_depmake
done

# start the Makefile
echo start Makefile ...
rm _tmp; touch _tmp
make -s -f $fn_depmake
# add ./obj/xxxxx*.o to the make-rules
sed -e 's/\(^[a-zA-Z]\)/.\/obj\/\1/' < _tmp > _tmp1
# add command to the make-rules
sed  -e '/\\/!a\
    $(CC) $($(*F)CFLAGS) -I$(<D) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@' < _tmp1  >> $fn_depIncl
# workaround for gcc generating cygdrive paths for some paths only
sed -i 's#/cygdrive/d#d:#' $fn_depIncl
rm _tmp _tmp1
rm $fn_depmake
echo done.
```

As you can see, I am currently using a workaround to convert those paths to mixed styled ones using `sed`, but I would like to know why this happens in the first place?

Example of a rule gone "wrong":

```
some.o: d:/some/path/A/some.cpp \
 d:/some/path/A/some.h \
 /cygdrive/d/some/path/B/subpathA/anotherheader.h \
 /cygdrive/d/some/path/B/subpathA/yetanotherheader.h \
 D:/some/path/B/subpathB/header.h
```

The main problem about this is that the resulting makefile is fed to a windows native make.exe, which has no idea what `/cygdrive/d/path` is supposed to be.

I have looked at the paths after each step, and they are all mixed style *until* `make -s -f $fn_depmake` is executed. Meaning, the occasional conversion to cygwin style paths is done by the `gcc -MM` command in the generated makefile.

It is always the same list of directories that get converted to `/cygdrive/d/pathA/somefile.cpp` style of paths. There is nothing unusual about the path, no spaces, only a-z/A-Z in name, length of the path is short, longest path is 76 characters including the filename, base path is 34 characters long.

How can I force gcc to generate mixed style paths?

Comment: Have you had a look at the actual commands that are emitted when calling GCC? My guess is the `-I` directives are the culprits. You probably don't need to do this preparsing by the way,  the GCC `-MMD`/`-MD` options can generate dependencies on the fly.

Comment: Yes, the `-I` paths are all mixed style paths, so it's not that, sadly. I even wrapped the `$sourcePaths` as well as `$path` in a `cygpath -m`, but the problem still persists. I will look at the `-MMD`/`-MD` options, but getting it to run is the first thing on my list atm.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the same problem on my project. I'm using `gmake.exe` from Cygwin on Windows.

One invocation of `gcc -MM` outputs both Windows-style paths (`C:/project/file.h`) and Cygwin-style paths (`/cygdrive/c/project/file.h`).

I don't know how to fix that yet, but I found what triggers the change to Cygwin-style paths. This happens when an include uses a relative path. So, when a file contains `#include "../file.h"`, then the output of `gcc -MM` will contain the absolute path of `file.h`, using a Cygwin-style path.